# grep -R one result per file

Tags: linux, grep, uniq

I'm trying to grep -R an exact version of apache.
I leave the include and the manuals, because its not necessary to change.
This is the command I'm using:

`grep -R 2.2.24 * | grep -v manual | grep -v include | cut -d':' -f 1`

I would like to know how to find one result per file?
Thanks

Comment: Consider adding `-F` to the first `grep` line, as `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions (it will match *any* character). `-F` will interpret the pattern as a simple string, with no special pattern-matching characteristics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cut` in your command suggests that you're looking to *list* files matching the specified *string*.

```
find . ! -path "*/manual/*" ! -path "*/include/*" -type f -exec grep -Fl 2.2.24 {} \;
```

should work for you.